# It looks to be hurting. VS. It looks to hurt

Tags: word-usage, present-continuous

What's the difference between them? I couldn't properly come up with any examples or contexts with them respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the website lexology.com, 4/20/19:

> **[1]** After success against Comcast with an earlier action at the ITC [the International Trade Centre], TiVo is once more seeking an exclusion order as **it looks to hurt** its rival’s cable platform.

*Looks* with with complement the active infinitive *to hurt*, and the infinitive taking the object *platform*. The meaning is "seeks to harm."

From the website www.barrons.com, 9/5/19:

> **[2]** The uncertainty **looks to be hurting** GE's share price.

*Looks* with complement the infinitive *to be*, and the infinitive taking as a complement the active progressive infinitive *to be hurting*. The meaning is "appears as inducing ongoing harm."

Note that there is a another, somewhat informal usage, as illustrated at the website www.nunesmagician.com, 3/2/18:

> **[3]** Since that game, he **looks to be hurting** and the numbers would indicate that something isn't right.

*Looks* with the infinitive *to be*, and the infinitive taking as a complement the adjectival present participle "hurting." The meaning is "appears as suffering."